# Raku infix operator in method-like syntax

Tags: methods, raku, infix-operator

In Raku, **infix** operators can be used like functions, e.g.:

```raku
1 + 2 ;           # 3
infix:<+>(1, 2) ; # 3
[+] 1, 2 ;        # 3
```

**Prefix** operators can be used with **method**-like syntax ([methodop](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#methodop_.:%3Cprefix_operator%3E)):

```raku
-1 ;             # -1
1.:<-> ;         # -1
```

So, (rather academic) question is, can **infix** operators also be used in **method**-like way, like `1.:<+>(2)` (which is wrong) ?

#### Loosely related alternatives

##### Currying

```raku
(1 + *)(2) ;     # 3
```

… that's function (sort of) definition and call, not a method call, nor method-like syntax.

##### Custom method

```raku
my method plus(Int $b --> Int){
  return self + $b;
}

1.&plus(2) ;     # 3
```

… but `+` name cannot be used, also that's not direct operator usage without an additional function definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```raku
1.&infix:<+>(2)
1.&[+](2)

1.&(*+*)(2)
1.&{$^a +$^b}(2)
```

Comment: wonderful and logical, I did not fidget enough

Comment: … look ma, without parens: `1.&[+]: 2`

Comment: s/fidget/fiddle/